# clang crashed during compilation of .cpp in Xcode in Release mode but ok in debug

Tags: c++, swift, crash, clang

I have a project where I have a .h, .cpp, and a bridging header, so basically trying to call some c++ code from swift. When i built and ran in Debug mode, things looked fine.

If I switch to release mode, it failed to build, and the crash happened during compilation from clang. Here's the message:

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: aarch64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/r5/bs8mgc751_bbl3gcths89jc00000gp/T/CBaseMath-8e4bd0.cpp
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/r5/bs8mgc751_bbl3gcths89jc00000gp/T/CBaseMath-8e4bd0.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Crash backtrace is located in
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /Users/kelvinchan/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/clang_<YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS>_<hostname>.crash
clang: note: diagnostic msg: (choose the .crash file that corresponds to your crash)
clang: note: diagnostic msg:
```

Any idea if there's something I should look, before trying to file a bug report for Apple as instructed? I tried to looked at the .crash file but i am not technical enough to understand it. It does not reference any of the c++ code I have.

Comment: This isn't a bug in your program, it's a bug in the compiler. So there's really nothing you need to look for. So try to create the most minimal program you can that replicates the crash (i.e. you need to create a [mcve]). Then follow the instructions told by the compiler about how to report it to the developers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, ok, sounds good. I will eliminate all swift stuff and just compile that single cpp and systematically narrow the code section.

Comment: The MCVE might already reveal which piece of your code provoked the clang bug. If not, you might try, too, compiling this MCVE with GCC (likely need to install first) with exactly the same compiler settings (as far as GCC and clang are compatible, but that's the case on quite some range). If it doesn't contain the same bug, you might get some hints in GCC's compilation logs that might help you find a workaround for so that you can continue development until clang is fixed. Or, as another workaround, you could just continue with GCC...

Comment: Worth mentioning is that you can try reproducing it on https://godbolt.org/. That also lets you quickly find out if the bug persists in the newest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a crash in your compiler, which is annoying. The best way to log a bug is to reduce this as much as possible.

The best way of doing so is with a program called [Creduce](http://embed.cs.utah.edu/creduce/). It's a program that requires a file and a script. The file is your starting situation. The script needs to prove your bug still exists.

In this case, your script could exist about the 2 compile commands and checking the return code. The file is simply your .CPP

With all of this, the program will throw away code ... and reduce the file as much as possible. I've seen 100 000 lines being reduced to 5.

A tricks: preprocessed files are larger though self-contained, this makes it easier to reduce.

Finally, you need a lot of time. You start it and it runs until it is reduced

If it runs in less than five minutes your script is faulty and you usually end up with an empty .CPP Expected time are in the range of hours.

Comment: I didn't end up logging a bug. I figured out a workaround that involved commenting out some #pragma ... interleave... The author of repo accepted the change. The length of the .cpp is still manageable I can manually extract the offensive subset. Thanks for you tips anyway.